# Deploy Vue Build On Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, bucket

I am running command "gcloud app deploy" from my "vue" app folder and at the last getting vue-cli error, attached snap for it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not post text as images, instead copy-paste it into your post and format it accordingly. Thx.

Comment: Please make your question valuable so that everyone benefits both from the question and the answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Screenshot links break or get deleted, rending your question worthless or confusing in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to deploy the app on GAE ( Google App Engine )?

If you are, the error might be caused because of GAE is not compatible with nodejs ( npm ), you need to deploy it in GAE flex if you want to use Vue of that way.

Another option could be, build the vue app and deploy it with another runtime, for example: python server; using the build as a static site.

Comment: Yes, i am deploying the app on GAE. I will try it with GAE flex.

Comment: Below is my app.yaml file, runtime: nodejs
env: flex
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(js|css|png|jpg|svg|ttf|ico|manifest))$
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/.*\.(js|css|png|jpg|svg|ttf)$
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

Comment: I didn't find anything wrong with your app.yaml, if you can try with GAE flex let me know if that solved it

Answer (score 1):

it seems like vue-cli-service isn't installed this is my cloudbuild.yaml if it helps
steps:

```
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
# Necessary for vue.js projects
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install', '-g', '@vue/cli']
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['test']
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'build']
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs12
handlers:
  # Serve all static files with urls ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\..+)$ 
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*\..+)$  # catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

Note: if your package.json isn't in your repository root you should define set in npm commands as:

```
    - name: node
      entrypoint: npm
   # --prefix and path:
      args: ['install','--prefix','myapp']
```

and for deployment in gcloud if app.yaml isn't in root either:

```
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy","myapp/app.yaml"]
```